# Regular language or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, regular-language

Let $L$ be a regular language over the alphabet $A=\{0, 1\}$. Is it true that the language of strings $0^n$, where binary representation of n $\in L$, is regular?

Comment: Do you know what the concatenation of two languages is?

Comment: Nevermind, it is easier than that. Remember $\{0\}$ is a regular language, so its Kleene star is also a regular language, This is exactly the language you want to prove is regular.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: You’ve misunderstood the question. The language is *not* $\{0\}^*$: it’s the set of strings $0^n$ such that the binary representation of $n$ is in some fixed regular language $L$. It might, for instance, be the set of all $0^n$ such that the binary representation of $n$ has exactly two ones.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Not necessarily. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\operatorname{bin}(n)$ be the binary representation of $n$. Suppose that $L$ is the language of the regular expression $10^*$; then the $n\in\Bbb N$ whose binary representations are in $L$ are precisely the powers of $2$. Show that the language $$\{0^n:\operatorname{bin}(n)\in L\}=\left\{0^{2^n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$$ is not regular.